# Bootstrap or jack-knife for crossvalidation of predictive model?

Tags: cross-validation, bootstrap, multivariate-regression, jackknife

Is a bootstrap or jack-knife method better for crossvalidation of a multivariate logistic regression based predictive model?

Comment: Bootstrap (and jack-knife) are typically techniques to estimate sampling distributions for parameters of interest. Cross-validation is a bit different, which compares out of sample predictive accuracy. Are you sure you don't mean "leave one out" cross-validation versus "leave n out" cross-validation?

Comment: Thanks Andy W. You are right. "Leave one out" cross-validation versus "leave n out" cross-validation would be more accurate. Any thoughts on which is better?